# How could I make the animation starts on scroll down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder how could I make this animation start either when you scroll down 1000px from the top or when you see this it on your screen?

I have tried different ways and zero luck, it  starts automatically when the website loads.

```js
$(".progress div").each(function() {
    var display = $(this),
        currentValue = parseInt(display.text()),
        nextValue = $(this).attr("data-values"),
        diff = nextValue - currentValue,
        step = (0 < diff ? 1 : -1);
    if (nextValue == "0") {
        $(display).css("padding", "0");
    } else {
        $(display).css("color", "#fff").animate({
            "width": nextValue + "%"
        }, "slow");
    }
});
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  background-color: #53dceb;
  height: 12px;
  -webkit-transition: width 1.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-bottom: 2rem">
    <h5 style="color: #666">test12 <span class="pull-right">50%</span></h5>
    <div class="progress">
        <div data-values="50" class="progress-bar" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried the .scroll() event? :)

Comment: up vote for explanatory question

Answer (score 0):

You were running the script on page load instead of 'onscroll' of the container element. In you case that might be `body`, in my case I put it inside `scrollable-div` for demonstration purposes.

Also, set the `width` in your css, otherwise the bar will look as if it were 100% wide.

```js
$(function(){
  var progressBar = $('.progress-bar'),
      display = $('#display'),
      initProgress = 0,
      targetProgress = parseInt(progressBar.attr("data-values"));
  
  $('#scrollable-div').on('scroll', function(){
    var currentValue = parseInt(display.text()),
        nextValue = targetProgress,
        diff = nextValue - currentValue,
        step = (0 < diff ? 1 : -1);
      if (nextValue == "0") {
        progressBar.css('width', '0%');
      } else {
        progressBar.css('width', nextValue+'%');
      }
  });
})
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  background-color: #53dceb;
  height: 12px;
  width: 0%;
  -webkit-transition: width 1.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollable-div" style="margin-bottom: 2rem; height: 150px; border: 1px solid #CCC; overflow: auto;">
    <h5 style="color: #666">test12 <span id="display" class="pull-right">50%</span></h5>
    <div class="progress">
      <div data-values="50" class="progress-bar" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 500px;"><!-- push down to show scroll --></div>
  </div>
<!-- JS code -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am trying it right now and it doesn't work. Literally now they are not showing any progress. :S

Comment: are you scrolling inside the gray box?

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved here ..  [How could I fix the animation speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42649303/how-could-i-fix-the-animation-speed)

```js
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

  var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

var IsViewed = false;

$(document).scroll(function() { // this code is run everytime you scroll
  console.log('scrolling'); // scroll a little bit and see how many times this is logged - that is how many times you run the code below

  $(".progress div").each(function() {
    var display = $(this),
      currentValue = parseInt(display.text()),
      nextValue = $(this).attr("data-values"),
      diff = nextValue - currentValue,
      step = (0 < diff ? 1 : -1);

    if (!display.is(':animated')) { // this checks to see if you are currently animating - if you are, you do not want to start the animation again (otherwise you get that slow start you were seeing)
      if (nextValue == "0") {
        $(display).css("padding", "0");
      } else {
        $(display).css("color", "#fff").animate({
          "width": nextValue + "%"
        }, "fast");
      }
    }

  });
});
```